# How to set object hook properly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, object, react-hooks

I have these states:

```
const [maintenanceTypeId, setMaintenanceTypeId] = useState(null);
const [maintenanceId, setMaintenanceId] = useState(null);

const [addedId, setAddedId] = useState({
    mainId : null,
    mainTypeId : null,
  });
```

I set states in these functions:
//setMaintenanceTypeId
//setAddedId

```
const addNewMainTypesList = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`${serverBaseUrl}/insertRowtoMainTypes`, {
        description: newMaintenanceList.description,
        title: newMaintenanceList.title
      });
      setMaintenanceTypeId(data[0]?.id);
      console.log("MaintenanceTypeId", maintenanceTypeId);
      //console.log("inserted type id",data[0]?.id);
      setAddedId({...addedId, mainTypeId : maintenanceTypeId});
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    const maintenanceList = await getMainTypes();
    // console.log("main list", maintenanceList);
    setMaintenanceList(maintenanceList);
  };
```

//setMaintenanceId
//setAddedId

```
const addNewMainTypes = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`${serverBaseUrl}/insertRowtoMain`, {
        nodeid: newMaintenance.nodeid,
        maintenancetype: newMaintenance.maintenancetype,
        personnel: newMaintenance.personnel,
        process: newMaintenance.process,
        date: newMaintenance.date,
      });
      setMaintenanceId(data[0]?.id);
      console.log("MaintenanceId", maintenanceId);
      setAddedId({...addedId, mainId : maintenanceId});
      //console.log("inserted main id",data[0]?.id);
      
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
```

I am console logging the addedId state in a submitHandler.

```
 const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    addNewMainTypesList();
    getMain();
    getMainTypes();
    addNewMainTypes();


    console.log("addedId",addedId);

  }
```

Here is the console. As you can see,  I can not get the `maintenanceTypeId`. How can I fix this?

[image: console]

Comment: @Daniel It did not work

Comment: edit: is it possible, that your `setAddedId` in `addNewMainTypes` overrides the `mainTypeId`? Check what's in `addedId`, I'd guess it says `mainTypeId: null`

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is an asynchronous function. In other words, it won't directly update a given state.

In your case `setMaintenanceTypeId` is not directly updating `maintenanceTypeId`.

In order, to make it update directly, use inside of it an anonymous function, like this:

```
setMaintenanceTypeId(mTypeId => data[0]?.id);
```

It would be also better if you do the same for `setAddedId` (though not mandatory):

```
setAddedId(addedId => {...addedId, mainTypeId : maintenanceTypeId});
```

Let me know if this still doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed my problem by using previous state.